# Needs to retrieve data first and then update the new entry into DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to retrieve data from the database first and then update the table with the new entry, following is my code but I am having an error:

> "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed."

I know I need to open the datareader by commenting `dr1.close`, but as soon as I did that I face an another exception:

> "there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first. vb.net"

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Officer_Module_GST_id_password
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim sscript As String
    Dim sms As New smsgw
    Dim mail As New MailSender
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim objconn As New connectioncls
    Dim name As String
    Dim pid As String
    Dim pwd As String
    Dim email_sent As Integer
    Dim email_status As String
    Dim mobile As String
    Dim message As String
    Dim subject As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim mtext As String

    Protected Sub validatedeal_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles validatedeal.Click
        containertwo.Visible = True
        txt_subject.Text = "Communication of the Provisional Identification Number and Password"
        txt_mail.Text = "Instance mail"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnsendmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        objconn.openconn()
        cmd.Connection = objconn.conn
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Trade_name,provissional_id,access_token,reg_mobile_no,reg_email_id,email_status,isnull(no_of_email_sent,0) from Provisional_details"
        Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While (dr1.Read())

            name = dr1(0).ToString()
            pid = dr1(1).ToString()
            pwd = dr1(2).ToString()
            mobile = dr1(3).ToString()
            email = dr1(4).ToString()
            email_status = dr1(5).ToString()
            email_sent = dr1(6).ToString()
            subject = "subject to instance"
            mtext = "new instance email"
            message = "new instance message"
            Try
                MailSender.SendEmail("riteshbhatt93" + "@gmail.com", "rock_on", email, subject, mtext, System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Text, "")
                Try
                    Call sms.SendSMSUsingNICGW(mobile, message)
                Catch
                    sscript = "<script language=javascript>alert('Message not sent!!')</script>"
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Empty", sscript)
                    sscript = Nothing
                    Exit Try
                Finally
                End Try

                Try
                    Call sms.SendSMSUsingMGOVGW(mobile, message)
                Catch
                    sscript = "<script language=javascript>alert('Message not sent!!')</script>"
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Empty", sscript)
                    sscript = Nothing
                    Exit Try
               Finally
               End Try
            Catch

                Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
                cmd1.Connection = objconn.conn
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobile)
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_status", "NO")
                cmd1.CommandText = "Update Provisional_details set Email_sent =  @Email_status where reg_mob_no = @mobile"
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd1.Parameters.Clear()
                Exit Sub
            Finally
            End Try

            dr1.Close()
            Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
            cmd2.Connection = objconn.conn
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobile)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_status", "YES")
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailsent", email_sent + 1)
            cmd2.CommandText = "Update Provisional_details set email_status =  @Email_status,no_of_email_sent = @emailsent  where reg_mobile_no = @mobile"

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd2.Parameters.Clear()
        End While

        sscript = "<script language=javascript>alert('Your Mail has been sent to all applied dealers!!')</script>"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Empty", sscript)
        sscript = Nothing

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Error tells you everything you need to know

Comment: T.S. error shows "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. as soon as i comment dr.close() another exception "there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first. vb.net" occurs i mean m with this loop if close the datareader than the former error occurs again

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Currently it's very hard to read.

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: You cannot use the same connection for a `DataReader` query and an `Upate` command. The `DataReader` must be disposed before executing the update.

Comment: Alex B sir, suggest me an another way to do it, but the flow should be the same,first reads the data from the table and then update it before reading the next data and yes it is SQL SERVER

Comment: Use DataSet with DataAdapter. Create Select and Update commands. Load dataset, modify values and issue "update" - everything will be updated

Comment: You *cannot* read the data and update it before reading the next data. Either you use the techniques T.S. mentioned or you change your flow. E.g. Read all data, store the results in a collection, loop the collection and do the Updates.

Comment: No. I guess you misunderstood what SO is. It is not a code writing service.

Comment: "can you write me the whole code of it" - we will not do it. You go to MSDN, use google, etc. for examples of how to do it. As far as SO mission concerned - your question is already answered.

Comment: Ok  thanks,Also using dataset I will get a list which needs to be updated after the while loop executes, but I want to select a row from multiple rows and update the row before reading the next row all in a loop, also I cannot update it later coz the data in the table will be increasing dynamically.

Comment: Why not use stored procedure with table variable to hold old data and return back?

Comment: oh yes thanks Tony Dong!!! It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I've pared this down to just the method that matters (like you should have done when posting the question). Updates are in the method, using comments to annotate what's going on.

```vb
Protected Sub btnsendmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Best practice in .Net is use a brand new connection instance for most DB calls. Really. 
    'Don't try to be clever and re-use one connection. Just use the same string.
    Dim connString As String = "Connection String Here"

    'Using block will guarantee connection closes properly, even if an exception is thrown
    Using cn   As New SqlConnection(connString), _
          cmd  As New SqlCommand("Select Trade_name,provissional_id,access_token,reg_mobile_no,reg_email_id,email_status,isnull(no_of_email_sent,0) from Provisional_details", cn), _
          cn2  As New SqlConnection(connString), _
          cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Update Provisional_details set email_status =  @Email_status,no_of_email_sent = @emailsent  where reg_mobile_no = @mobile", cn2)

        'Define your parameters as early as possible, and be explicit about parameter types and lengths
        ' This will avoid potentially crippling performance gotchas
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 14)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Email_status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@emailsent", SqlDbType.Int)

        'Separate SQL statements in a tight loop like this is one of the few places to re-use a connection object... 
        ' Even here, it should be a BIG RED FLAG that there's a better way to handle this whole process that avoids multiple calls to the DB.
        ' For example, it might be better to assume success, Update the DB accordingly in the original statement, and then only write failures back when needed
        cn2.Open() 
        cn.Open()  

        dr1 As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While (dr1.Read())
            'Best practice in .Net are to declare these variables in the method where you use them
            Dim name As String = dr1(0).ToString()
            Dim pid As String = dr1(1).ToString()
            Dim pwd As String = dr1(2).ToString() 'You're not really storing passwords in plain-text are you? Please say, "No".
            Dim mobile As String = dr1(3).ToString()
            Dim email As String = dr1(4).ToString()
            Dim email_status As String = dr1(5).ToString()
            Dim email_sent As Integer = dr1.GetInt32(6) 'It's a number. You do math on it later. Get the INTEGER value
            Dim subject As String = "subject to instance"
            Dim mtext As String = "new instance email"
            Dim message As String = "new instance message"

            cmd2.Parameters("@mobile").Value = mobile

            Try
                MailSender.SendEmail("riteshbhatt93" + "@gmail.com", "rock_on", email, subject, mtext, System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Text, "")

                Try                       
                    ' Also... the "Call" keyword is a vb6-era relic that has no purpose any more. Don't use it
                    sms.SendSMSUsingMGOVGW(mobile, message)
                Catch
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Empty", "<script language=javascript>alert('Message not sent!!')</script>")

                    'Don't set values to "Nothing" to free them in VB.Net. 
                    'It doesn't help the way it used to in vb6/vbscript, and can actually be HARMFUL in rare cases in .Net
                End Try

                ' Do you really mean to try both gateways, even if the first succeeds?
                '  Because that's what the original code is doing.
                Try                       
                    sms.SendSMSUsingNICGW(mobile, message)
                Catch
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Empty", "<script language=javascript>alert('Message not sent!!')</script>")

                    'No need to call Exit Try here, 
                    ' and no need for an empty Finally section
                End Try

            Catch
                 cmd2.Parameters("@emailsent") = email_sent
                 cmd2.Parameters("@Email_status") = "NO"
                 cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Try

            cmd2.Parameters("@Email_status").Value = "YES"
            cmd2.Parameters("@emailsent").Value = email_sent + 1
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks it helped!! Although i stored the parameters in an array list and later at the end of while loop ,executes the update command with the stored elements of the array list.

Comment: ArrayLists are evil. They only exist for compatibility with pre-.Net 2.0 code, and should no longer be used otherwise. Use List(Of T) instead, even if you need List(Of Object).